# Standard ml loop troubles

Tags: loops, smlnj, ml

I am setting up a function that will simulate a loop until a condition is met.

My overall plan is to use recursion but I am trying to get the basics down first.

I got a basic function working using an If statement that is seeing what the value of X is.  I plan to use recursion to use X as an counter but I will get to that later.

My main concern right now is, it seems I can only do 1 command after the "then" statement.

```
fun whileloop (x,a) =
    if (x<4)
    then a+1 
    else a;
```

So this function works perfectly fine, but it seems the only command I can do is the a+1.  If I try to perform any other command after that, before the else...it fails.

For example, the below code will fail on me.

```
fun whileloop (x,a) =
    if (x<4)
    then a+1 
    print "Testing"
    else a;
```

my ultimate goal is to create a loop that will perform several actions over and over until X reaches zero.  I need to perform like 5-6 actions using different functions.

Comment: If you've received a complete answer and now have follow-up questions, you should ask them as new questions.

Comment: `a + 1` is not a "command", and doesn't actually *do* anything. There's no point evaluating `a + 1` and discarding the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can evaluate several expressions in sequence using the semicolon operator:

```
( e1; e2; ...; eN )
```

For example,

```
fun iter n f = if n = 0 then () else (f n; iter (n-1) f)
```

Comment: This helps with expressions yes, thank you very much.