# Standard ML running multiple functions in a loop (Using recursion or any other means)

Tags: loops, recursion, sml, smlnj, ml

I have defined three different functions that will perform calculations and return a value.  These functions will consistently be redefining a variable until a specific condition is reached.  I am having issues getting these to run in a "loop" scenario.  I know functional languages are not best for performing loops and you should use recursion...but I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how to perform this.

I will make some real simple arbitrary functions to explain my situation.

```
fun add_them (a,b) =
    a+b;

fun substract_them (c,d) =
    c-d;

fun add_them2 (e,f) =
    e-f;

val a = 5;
val b = 7;
val c = 10;
val d = 1;

val a = add_them (a,b);
val d = add_them2 (c,d);
```

So let's say I want to run the last two lines a 1000 times.  So Val A and Val D will keep getting added up to a huge number.  Now I could literally copy and paste those two lines a 1000 times and get the result I want..but this of course defeats the purpose of programming :)

I was trying to create a loop that I can throw these two functions in.  I was coming up with something like below, but I would have no idea how to incorporate these two.  Perhaps I am going at this completely backwards.

```
fun whileloop (x,a) =
    if (a<1)
    then x 
    else whileloop(x+1,a-1);
```

So my goal was to insert those above val a and val d expressions into another function using recursion and run it a certain amount of times.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I already showed you a solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44319861/standard-ml-loop-troubles/44324554?noredirect=1#comment75693668_44324554 -- the function `iter` I gave in my answer does exactly what you describe. (However, I wonder if what you describe is what you actually _want_.)

Comment: I will look deeper into this when I get home but ultimately i am trying to run three different equations a 1000 times and return the value of each equation.  The problem is...the second equation uses the first equations value, and the third equation uses the second equations value.

Comment: I also second your statement that the way I am describing it is perhaps wrong.  I am going at this like it's C++ so I am perhaps tackling this whole program wrongly.  I hope my previous comment explains my situation a little better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function that simply iterates another function n times is given in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44319861/standard-ml-loop-troubles/44324554). But it sounds like you want to apply a given function n times to a seed, like so:

```
f (f (f (f ... (f x) ... )))
```

That can be accomplished by the following function:

```
fun repeat n f x = if n = 0 then x else repeat (n-1) f (f x)
```

For example,

```
val n = repeat 20 (fn => n + 1) 0
```

results in 20.

Or perhaps you want to repeat based on a condition instead of a count:

```
fun repeatWhile p f x = if p x then repeatWhile p f (f x) else x
```

For example,

```
val n = repeatWhile (fn x => x > 0) (fn x => x - 1) 20
```

returns 0.

Both functions are polymorphic, so also work with tuples. For example:

```
val (x, y) = repeatWhile (fn (a, b) => a > 0) (fn (a, b) => (a-1, b+1)) (20, 0)
```

returns (0, 20).

If you dislike using two separate function parameters for condition and "action", you can also combine them by having it return a pair:

```
fun repeatWhile2 f x =
    let val (c, y) = f x in if c then repeatWhile2 f y else x end
```

Then:

```
repeatWhile (fn (a, b) => (a > 0, (a-1, b+2))) (20, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with all of these SML questions.  I truly do appreciate it.  I have another question I posted that is similar to this example but is asking for an additional IF statement.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44489424/standard-ml-multiple-condition-statement