# Standard ML multiple condition statement

Tags: if-statement, sml, smlnj

I am about finished with a script I am writing but I have one last condition statement to add to my function.

```
fun whileloop (x:real,a:int,b:real) =
    if (a<1)
    then (x,a,b) 
    else whileloop(x+1.0,a-1,b-1.0)
```

This is my current loop I have created.  It is basically accomplishing everything I need under one exception.  I want it to exit its loop once the b variable hits zero[if this happens before a reaches zero).  I believe Standard ML will not let me do a condition statement for a real variable...such as b<1.0.  just to give you an idea of what I am trying to accomplish...I want the following code to work below:

```
fun whileloop (x:real,a:int,b:real) =
    if (a<1 or b<1.0)
    then (x,a,b) 
    else whileloop(x+1.0,a-1,b-1.0)
```

of course this code does not work due to the syntax and a condition statement being checked against a real number...but how could I accomplish this task while keeping my skeleton somewhat intact.  I simply want to add another if condition statement to the existing skeleton.  In C++ this was a fairly simple task.

Comment: Wrong keyword. `or` => `orelse`. With that change your second function works as expected.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize I was so close!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer.  Thanks to John Coleman.

```
fun whileloop (x:real,a:int,b:real) =
    if (a<1 orelse b<1.0)
    then (x,a,b) 
    else whileloop(x+1.0,a-1,b-1.0)
```